# Bind Obserable Collection to MenuFlyoutSubItem in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Currently I get "The property "Items" does not have an accessible setter." How could I modify this control to allow me to bind a collection to it and maybe just set on of the properties of the objects in the collection to the text property of the items?

```
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Button" Icon="Add" Label="stuff">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b1" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b2" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b3" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b4" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b5" ></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="bb1" Items="{Binding MyList}" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
```

Comment: Yep. Here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/xaml-how-to-add-itemssource-to-windows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. If you take a look [at documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutsubitem.items), you will see that *Items* has only a getter, so cannot set collection to it. You can get collection reference and then for example *Add* items to it, but it seems that this works until the flyout is shown. After that no changes are applied (though I don't have much time now to play with it). Here is some code, where I've tried something with attached property:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="click">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b1"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="b2"/>
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem Name="mysub" local:MenuExtension.MyItems="{Binding Options}" Text="Choosable items"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="modify" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public static class MenuExtension
{
    public static List<MenuFlyoutItem> GetMyItems(DependencyObject obj)
    { return (List<MenuFlyoutItem>)obj.GetValue(MyItemsProperty); }

    public static void SetMyItems(DependencyObject obj, List<MenuFlyoutItem> value)
    { obj.SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems", typeof(List<MenuFlyoutItem>), typeof(MenuExtension),
        new PropertyMetadata(new List<MenuFlyoutItem>(), (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Filling collection");
            var menu = sender as MenuFlyoutSubItem;
            menu.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in e.NewValue as List<MenuFlyoutItem>) menu.Items.Add(item);
        }));
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public List<MenuFlyoutItem> Options { get; set; } = new List<MenuFlyoutItem>
    {
        new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item" },
        new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item" },
        new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item" }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Options = new List<MenuFlyoutItem> { new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Modified" } };
        RaiseProperty(nameof(Options));
//      mysub.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "modified" }); // even this cannot be done
    }
}
```

Maybe you can play with some templates, bind in button and then exchange the whole flyout, or try something different

Comment: isn't there a way to edit or create something like it?

Comment: @shady I've modified the answer to show some more information. It doesn't solve the problem, but maybe will give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify your example to do exactly what I wanted it to do. instead of casting the new value to a menu item, I casted it to a list of my model so I could map a property value to the text property of the new menu items.

Comment: @shady So it means that you have changed the text of old menu items? Have you iterated through menu's items to find the sub menu and then change elements? Or something other?

Comment: In your foreach loop under the items clear, I just changed the as List<MenuFlyoutItem>) to as List<MyClass> then did menu.items.add(new MenuFlyoutItem() {Text=item.someProperty})

Comment: @shady And is it working? I mean - does it work when you modify the menu after it has been shown for the very first time? I have tried couple of things and I've problems to modify the flyout once it has been show - e.g. you click button to show menu, then close it, then modify somehow, then show once again.

Comment: Ah, my binding is onetime only. I generate the list runtime on startup, then bind it to the list from my viewmodel to the menuflyoutsubitem.

Comment: @shady Oh, in that case it will definitely work. Thanks for info.