# Bind and update ObservableCollection<T> to MenuFlyoutSubItem

Tags: c#, .net, list, uwp, observablecollection

I am developing a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app in Visual Studio 2015. I am currently facing this problem that I want to add items to a `MenuFlyoutSubItem`. Basically, the items are a collection of Playlists.

My question is this:
How can I bind an `ObservableCollection` or a `List` to a `MenuFlyoutSubItem` and update the items when a new item is added? I already tried this from here: [Bind Obserable Collection to MenuFlyoutSubItem in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839279/bind-obserable-collection-to-menuflyoutsubitem-in-uwp)

```
public static class MenuExtension
{
public static List<MenuFlyoutItem> GetMyItems(DependencyObject obj)
{ return (List<MenuFlyoutItem>)obj.GetValue(MyItemsProperty); }

public static void SetMyItems(DependencyObject obj, List<MenuFlyoutItem> value)
{ obj.SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value); }

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems", typeof(List<MenuFlyoutItem>), typeof(MenuExtension),
    new PropertyMetadata(new List<MenuFlyoutItem>(), (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Filling collection");
        var menu = sender as MenuFlyoutSubItem;
        menu.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in e.NewValue as List<MenuFlyoutItem>) menu.Items.Add(item);
    }));
```

}

This is good as far as the items do not change but in my scenario `Items` will change. How can I add updating to this extension? If the Flyout is created again on each popup then it will update but I don't know how to implement this behaviour.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the Flyout is created again on each popup then it will update but I don't know how to implement this behaviour.

You are right, I removed all the items of the `MenuFlyout` and add them again. And the flyout is updated. Directly update the sub items of `MenuFlyoutSubItem` doesn't have any effect on surface.

So to do that you can modify the codes like below:

1. Binding the Items to the `MenuFlyout` instead of `MenuFlyoutSubItem` in XAML:

   ```
   <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
           <Button Content="click" Name="myBtn">
               <Button.Flyout>
                   <MenuFlyout local:FlyoutMenuExtension.MyItems="{Binding OptionItems}">
                   </MenuFlyout>
           </Button.Flyout>
       </Button>
       <Button Content="modify" Click="Button_Click"/>
   </StackPanel>
   ```
2. Init/update the `MenuFlyout` items in code-behind:

   ```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

       public List<MenuFlyoutItemBase> OptionItems { get; set; }

       public List<MenuFlyoutItemBase> InitFlyoutItems()
       {
           var list = new List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>
           {
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 1" },
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 2" },
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 3" },
               new MenuFlyoutSubItem { Text="Start Item 4"  }
           };
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Old Sub Item 1" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Old Sub Item 2" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Old Sub Item 3" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Old Sub Item 4" });
           return list;
       }

       public List<MenuFlyoutItemBase> UpdateFlyoutItems()
       {
           var list = new List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>
           {
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 1" },
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 2" },
               new MenuFlyoutItem {Text="Start item 3" },
               new MenuFlyoutSubItem { Text="Start Item 4"  }
           };
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "New Sub Item 1" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "New Sub Item 2" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "New Sub Item 3" });
           ((MenuFlyoutSubItem)list[3]).Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "New Sub Item 4" });
           return list;
       }

       public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = this;
       }

       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
           OptionItems = InitFlyoutItems();
           RaiseProperty(nameof(OptionItems));
           base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
       }



       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           OptionItems=UpdateFlyoutItems();
           RaiseProperty(nameof(OptionItems));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Modify the `MenuExtension`:

   ```
   public static class FlyoutMenuExtension
   {
       public static List<MenuFlyoutItemBase> GetMyItems(DependencyObject obj)
       {
           return (List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>)obj.GetValue(MyItemsProperty);
       }
       public static void SetMyItems(DependencyObject obj, List<MenuFlyoutItemBase> value)
       {
           obj.SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value);
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems",
               typeof(List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>),
               typeof(FlyoutMenuExtension),
               new PropertyMetadata(new List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>(), (sender, e) => {
                   var menu = sender as MenuFlyout;
                   menu.Items.Clear();
                   foreach (var item in e.NewValue as List<MenuFlyoutItemBase>)
                   {
                       menu.Items.Add(item);
                   }
               }));
   }
   ```

Here is the complete Demo: [MenuFlyoutSubItemBindingSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/MenuFlyoutSubItemBindingSample)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried what @Elvis Xia - MSFT suggested, and although it didn't work for me, it showed me the way to the solution. I got a compilation error (using x:Bind) in one of the auto generated .cs files, saying that it couldn't convert from MenuFlyout to FrameworkElement. When I used 'Binding' instead, I managed to compile, but the menu did not update. So, what I did was simply to move the dependency property one level up (or 2 levels, if you consider `<Button.Flyout>`), to the button itself:

```
<Button local:ButtonExtension.MenuFlyout="{x:Bind MainViewModel.Menu, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Here's the ButtonExtension class:

```
public static class ButtonExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuFlyoutProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MenuFlyout",
            typeof(MenuFlyout), typeof(ButtonExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(new MenuFlyout(), (sender, e) =>
            {
                var button = sender as Button;
                button.Flyout = e.NewValue as MenuFlyout;
            }));

    public static MenuFlyout GetMenuFlyout(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MenuFlyout)obj.GetValue(MenuFlyoutProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMenuFlyout(DependencyObject obj, MenuFlyout value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MenuFlyoutProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Here's the property in the ViewModel:

```
public MenuFlyout Menu { get; private set; }
```